# Hide subcategory icon in topmenu

Tags: magento-1.8, menu

In my magento shop I don't want to display icons for subcategories in topmenu. But I wan't to leave them in top menu. If I don't select icon for subcategory I get missing img include. You can see screenshot below.

[image]

Code that generates output is:

```
$urls = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$child->getData('thumbnail');

        $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . '<img src="'.$urls.'" style="width:20px; height:20px;"/>  '
            . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';

        if ($child->hasChildren()) {
            if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
                $html .= '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
            }
            $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">';
            $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass);
            $html .= '</ul>';

            if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
                $html .= '</div>';
            }
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
```

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Marius for pointing me to the right way. Your code needs some improvements, because img src still remains in cart. But code below solved my problem:

```
        if ($child->getData('thumbnail')){ //check if there is an image
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . '<img src="'.$urls.'" style="width:20px; height:20px;"/>  '
            . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>'; //build the img tag
        }
        else {
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
            . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
        }
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: You can mark this as accepted if it is the working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
if ($child->getData('thumbnail')){ //check if there is an image
    $urls = '<img src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$child->getData('thumbnail').'" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />'; //build the img tag
}
else {
    $urls = ''; //no image = no img tag
}

$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $urls . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';

if ($child->hasChildren()) {
    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
    }
    $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">';
    $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass);
    $html .= '</ul>';
    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '</div>';
    }
}
$html .= '</li>';
```

I hope I didn't miss a quote or double quote.

Comment: With a little modification of your code I did solve my problem. I will post full answer later, because my reputation is too low to post solution so quick.